# getting maven error when trying to build on IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am trying to work with Spring boot and Vue.

This is the tutorial(github repo: https://github.com/danvega/full-stack-java-vue/blob/master/pom.xml)

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.johndoe</groupId>
    <artifactId>full-stack-springboot-vue</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>full-stack-springboot-vue</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <node.version>v14.16.0</node.version>
        <npm.version>6.14.11</npm.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.6</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Copy Vue frontend into Spring Boot target static folder</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/frontend/dist</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is the error I m getting:
[image]

When I try to run this command, I get the error above:

```
mvn clean package
```

I installed apache maven 3.8.1 and also added in my environment variables.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried first to google the problem and deleting .m2 folder did not help

Comment: Set up `JAVA_HOME` environment variable that points to the valid JDK installation home and reboot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you so much sir. You are the best!